# Why doesn't my string get trimmed when I call Trim on it?

Tags: string, delphi, trim

I added a space to my string, but Trim does not delete this space. Why not?

```
str:=tstringlist.create;
str.LoadFromFile(s);
Trim(str.strings[1]);
str.Free;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Trim` is a function and does not modify its parameter in-place. You mean to write:

```
str.strings[1] := Trim(str.strings[1]);
```

Answer (score 16):

Trim returns modified string instead of changing string you passing into it.

```
trimmed:= Trim(str.strings[1]);
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the code work as you want, do this:

```
str:=tstringlist.create;
str.LoadFromFile(s);
str.strings[1]:= Trim(str.strings[1]); //This line was modified
str.Free;
```

If you want to save the trimmed string to the file (overriding the file), then do this:

```
str:=tstringlist.create;
str.LoadFromFile(s);
str.strings[1]:= Trim(str.strings[1]); //This line was modified
str.SaveToFile(s);                     //This line was added
str.Free;
```

Comment: If you want to trim all lines you can do this:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trim all strings(lines) in the string list do this:

```
str:=tstringlist.create;
str.LoadFromFile(s);
for i:=0 to str.Count - 1 do
  str.strings[i]:= Trim(str.strings[i]); 
str.Free;
```